# ubuntu store doesn't load apps

Tags: upgrade

[image]

How can i solve this problem without having to kill the app every other time. Also clicking on automatic updates setting dialog box does nothing in the snap store.
Ubuntu version 21.10

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1390089/edit) the question to add that information.

Comment: Snap store is just ridiculous! You should use a good application like gnome software. It's fairly good and doesn't have any issues. N.B: Snap store is a modified version of Gnome Software

Comment: @Someone OP may not know the difference between the two, or how to install gnome software. Please write it into an answer.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Done, please review it.

Comment: @Someone Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known issue. If you refer to the Launchpad Page of Ubuntu Software, you'll see a handful of bug reports regarding the same with no answers from the developers. As a result, in *Jammy* 22.04, they've chosen to use Gnome software instead. Gnome software is working fine without any issues. You can install gnome-software using:

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt install gnome-software
```

If you want to remove the Ubuntu software app:

```
$ sudo snap remove snap-store
```

Gnome software is way better than the default application centre. The user interface is nearly the same.

**Note**: Ubuntu Snap Store is a re-designed version of Gnome-Software but unfortunately with bugs.

---

You can launch gnome software using:

```
 $ gnome-software
```

You can also launch it using the application overview.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Gnome software Icon]

Here is the UI of Gnome Software in Ubuntu 21.10:

[image: Gnome Software UI]

You can install additional plugins for it too. For example, you can run the following command to enable the `snap` plugin in Gnome Software:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

If you want to enable flatpak support then you can run:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

Comment: You helped me a lot the open network settings dialog now works. And the app it 10 times better

Comment: @BonnieMunene Awesome! I'm glad it's working as expected. You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark button near the vote count. Have fun!

Comment: I upgraded from 21 to 22, and alas Gnome Software was not part of 22.04; perhaps because I upgraded? It was weird, I had some weird Snapfish (?) store alongside Ubuntu store, and neither one worked (while on 21, 22 removed the non-Ubuntu store). Snaps never updated. You'd think Ubuntu would ensure their software stores would be fully functional. In any case, followed your suggestion because 8 months later (from your answer), Ubuntu Store still bugs out.